# Connection error Google Cloud Function to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Using the example code for connecting a cloud function to Cloud SQL, I successfully created a new function with slightly different output. It ran fine for a while. Now, with no changes whatsoever to the code, I am getting a OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"). Here's the full error:

```
sql-test-function-1
szzv41dltb8k
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 570, in connect sock.connect(self.unix_socket) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 297, in run_http_function result = _function_handler.invoke_user_function(flask.request) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 199, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 192, in call_user_function return self._user_function(request_or_event) File "/user_code/main.py", line 50, in mysql_demo mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect return Connection(*args, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__ self.connect() File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 629, in connect raise exc pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I've seen numerous examples of people having a similar problem both here and on Google GitHub support and have tried all their solutions (enabling Cloud SQL Admin API, implementing the answer in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325928/cloud-functions-connection-refused-when-connecting-to-cloud-sql), etc.) but I keep getting the same error. I've tried restarting the SQL instance as well as creating a new function with the same code in a Chrome Incognito window to avoid caching issues: same error.

Here is my code for the cloud function:

```
from os import getenv

import pymysql
from pymysql.err import OperationalError

# TODO(developer): specify SQL connection details
CONNECTION_NAME = getenv(
  'INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME',
  'la-cloud-functions:us-central1:cf-sql-1')
DB_USER = getenv('MYSQL_USER', 'root')
DB_PASSWORD = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'root')
DB_NAME = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'gallery')

mysql_config = {
  'user': DB_USER,
  'password': DB_PASSWORD,
  'db': DB_NAME,
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'cursorclass': pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
  'autocommit': True
}

# Create SQL connection globally to enable reuse
# PyMySQL does not include support for connection pooling
mysql_conn = None


def __get_cursor():
    """
    Helper function to get a cursor
      PyMySQL does NOT automatically reconnect,
      so we must reconnect explicitly using ping()
    """
    try:
        return mysql_conn.cursor()
    except OperationalError:
        mysql_conn.ping(reconnect=True)
        return mysql_conn.cursor()


def mysql_demo(request):
    global mysql_conn

    # Initialize connections lazily, in case SQL access isn't needed for this
    # GCF instance. Doing so minimizes the number of active SQL connections,
    # which helps keep your GCF instances under SQL connection limits.
    if not mysql_conn:
        try:
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)
        except OperationalError:
            # If production settings fail, use local development ones
            mysql_config['unix_socket'] = f'/cloudsql/{CONNECTION_NAME}'
            mysql_conn = pymysql.connect(**mysql_config)

    # Remember to close SQL resources declared while running this function.
    # Keep any declared in global scope (e.g. mysql_conn) for later reuse.
    with __get_cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SELECT * from albums')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row is not None:
          print(row)
          row = cursor.fetchone()
```

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd be thrilled.

TIA - Joe

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by recreating the function in another project. I'm not sure why the Cloud SQL instance dropped the connection and could not connect, but once I re-established the connection, I was able to reapply the code from the function successfully. The Cloud Function to Cloud SQL connectivity is still officially in beta, so it may just be a temporary glitch.